# non-english languages iOS apps XE4 issue

Tags: delphi, arabic, delphi-xe4, persian

I tried non-english languages such as Arabic Language in my hello world XE4 iOS App, but when running the App on the simulator or even on the device all non-english characters appears empty!

I tried MessageBox and this is OK, the problem is exists for components,
any clue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

AFAIK Firemonkey does not handle properly such [right-to-left languages](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Right-to-left).

This is a limitation.

But it does handle Unicode. That is, non English "non complex script" text can be rendered, like French, German, Russian, Greek. But FireMonkey does not handle complex scripting including ligatures and glyph shaping, and visual order arrangment.

MessageBox does not use Firemonkey, but the raw iOS API, so it works as expected, since the Delphi compiler kernel does handle Unicode.